# Best approaches on "filling" a json file , iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, file

I am working on an application and i need to send some data to my server. The data is in json format and more specific the json file looks like this :

```
{
    "eventData": {
        "eventDate": "Jun 13, 2012 12:00:00 AM",
        "eventLocation": {
            "latitude": 43.93838383,
            "longitude": -3.46
        },
        "text": "hjhj",
        "imageData": "raw data",
        "imageFormat": "JPEG",
        "expirationTime": 1339538400000
    },
    "type": "ELDIARIOMONTANES",
    "title": "accIDENTE"
}
```

So i have tried to hardcode the data in my json file and everything works ok. Now what i am trying to do is to fill my json file , using variables so everything can work automatcally when data changes. What would a good approach be for that?? Some sample code would be highly appreciated as i am very new to obj-c. Thanks for ur time! :D

### EDIT

Ok so an NSDictionary seems a nice way to go.
But how can i create a dictionary to look like the json format?? I ve only used dictionaries like this :

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"eventDate", @"eventLocation", @"latitude"  nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"object1", @"object2", @"object3", nil]; 
dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
```

For the langitude and longitude for example it is a pair of key and value but for the rest??

Answer (score 4):

All you need is a `NSDictionary` containing your keys and values. Since iOS5, you can proceed with the following code

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myDictionary 
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&error];        
if (!jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify , in the example the myDictionary is the NSDictionary where i should put my json variables and the last line of code is to convert to json format ready for post?

Comment: Right! Just fill `myDictionary` with the keys and values you want to see in your final json output.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was really straightforward and exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: @tile Can you please check my edited answer? I have one more question on the dictionary.

Comment: Sure: You have to use nested dictionaries, i.e. the object for key "eventData" will be a `NSDictionary`

Answer (score 2):

I have used this [library](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/downloads/list)  . It is very simple and useful. And for tutorial check this [site](http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c).